# Joomla 3 404 Page Not Working

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have Created article for 404 page and updated the 404 error page URL in error.php of my template. when i typed url example.com/something it redirects to Website home page instead of showing 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you updated your 404 error page url in error.php of your template.

But adding a simple php header redirect can solve your problem.

```
<?php

header("Location: http://yourdomain.com/your-custom-error-article.html");
die();

?>
```

Simply add this to the error.php of your template. This will redirect the visitor to the article page that you created.

Answer (score 0):

I had problem in one of my components router.php file. It gave some default if there was no matches. So Joomla would redirect to the default page of that component. I put this code to check if the catid was a number and raise error. Now error.php of template is working as intended with 404 page with 404 header.

```
    if (!is_numeric($catid[0])) return JError::raiseError(404, 'Ad not found');
```

Comment: If you are doing Joomla development, please join us at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.